# Mail syncing fails in javax.mail after installing Avast Anti Virus

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Mail syncing fails in javax.mail after installing Avast Anti Virus and gives the following Exception:-

```
INBOX.Archive javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
```

1. I have checked the certificates are present in the jre, so this issue should not persist.
2. After disabling the Anti virus everything goes back to normal and the syncing starts.

Note:Using Java 1.8

Comment: Maybe the AV includes a firewall that blocks the syncing...

Answer (score 1):

Avast is interposing on the connection between JavaMail and the mail server and is using its own certificate instead of passing through the certificate from the mail server.  You need to change the configuration of Avast to allow your JavaMail application to connect directly.

Comment: Ok let me try this and get back. Thanks

Comment: tried this and it worked but we are an email client app so we cannot go to each an every client and do this, can you provide any other solution.

Comment: I think you need to ask an Avast exert how to automate your reconfiguration of Avast to that Avast won't interfere with your  email product.